# RxJs using merge with of hangs on lastValueFrom

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

I'm writing a custom I18nLoader for nestjs.
There is a load method which is called in the following way

```
 if (!translations) {
      translations = await this.loader.load();
    }
    if (translations instanceof Observable) {
      this.translationsSubject.next(
        await lastValueFrom(translations.pipe(take(1))),
      );
    } else {
      this.translationsSubject.next(translations);
    }
```

Because I want my translations to be observables I implemented load method in the following way:

```
private events: Subject<void> = new Subject();

localizationService.subscribe(() => {
      this.events.next();
    });
...

  async parseTranslations() {
      // does some db query with prisma and returns an object
  }

  async load() {
     return merge(
          of(await this.parseTranslations()),
          this.events.pipe(switchMap(() => this.parseTranslations())),
        );
}
```

So basically whenever localizationService produces a value, it will generate a new value in the observable. And to make sure that lastValueFrom always gets some value, I added of operator that produces initial value.
Now observations:

1. translations is always undefined at the beginning of this method, so it gets recreated. Don't get confused with the first if.
2. As far as I understand any value produced by my translations observable will complete the await on lastValueFrom. That is done thanks to take(1) which completes observable after first event.
3. parseTranslations returns successfully

For some reason following code hangs forever on lastValueFrom. I tried to experiment with it and even changing load to this didn't solve the issue:

```
 async load() {
         return of(await this.parseTranslations())
    }
```

Comment: You have share half of the code and there's no repro. I've tried my best to understand, but I cannot help you. If you wish, feel free to create a minimal repro on stackblitz and maybe I'll be able to help out. And I said minimal repro, please don't just dump your entire codebase. Something minimal which highlights the issue and only that

Comment: Also, that won't solve it for you but FYI, most of the functions that accept observables also accept promises directly. I've made a small Stackblitz to demo that https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-viz8gq?file=index.ts so you can really simplify your merge

Comment: @maxime1992 hey, I've tried to reproduce this but it works fine. It looks like it must be something with i18n nest library. I'd need to debug it and check, looks like it's not related to rxjs. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear. And that's also why I always ask for a *minimal* repro. It lot of cases, it just points towards a different error than originally though :) Good luck debugging the i18n lib

Comment: zone.js can not patch async await, so Change Detection in your app will barely work 
 (unless it's zoneless). Do not use async await in Angular apps.